# Magento 2 add custom layout in order email

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to add a custom field in order email template.

I configured in total.phtml in public_html/theme_name/vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order. It's working.

I tried to configure in

items.phtml in public_html/theme_name/vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order. It had no effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` after change in theme.

Comment: how to run this command?

Comment: using terminal to access root folder of magento and run this command